# Import a vcard 3.0 automatically into android contacts (Android 2.1)

Tags: android, import, contacts, vcf-vcard

I'm trying to import a vcard (vers. 3.0) automatically into the android contacts.
Within the contact manager there is an option to import a vcf file stored on the sd-card into the contacts. How can I trigger this function with handing over a file?

Answer (score 3):

I used for one of my projects the following solution. It worked perfectly. As the vCard lib I used cardme v.0.26, which supports vcard version 3.0 as well.

note: file name is stored in res/values/strings.xml...

```
        /*
         * Create file. This file has to be readable, otherwise the contact
         * application cannot access the file via URI to read the vcard
         * string.
         */
```

// this var contains your vCard as a string
String vcardString;

```
        FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput(
                getResources().getText(R.string.app_vcard_file_name)
                        .toString(), MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        // write vcard string to file
        osw.write(vcardString);
        // ensures that all buffered bytes are written
        osw.flush();
    } catch (NotFoundException e) {
        // ..
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // ...
    } finally {
        if (osw != null) {
            try {
                osw.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
    // let the os handle the import of the vcard to the Contacts
    // application
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://"
            + getFileStreamPath(
                    getResources().getText(R.string.app_vcard_file_name)
                            .toString()).getAbsolutePath()), "text/x-vcard");
    startActivity(i);
```